# Why am I getting a "unique "key" prop" error in my ASp.NET React Project when I have defined a key?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I'm working in a new react project, I'm trying to find my pace with it and started looking at simple ways of fetching data.  Using a simple list of data I am attempting to output it to a list.  When I try to run the page I get the following error:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop. Check the render method of `FetchData`.

I started to search around for answers and found many articles on here saying that you need to add a key value.  I thought I had done this but it's not working.  The key value is, in this case, the `Id` of the car but I'm still receiving the error.

I looked at the React documentation and I got the same answer, add a unique key.  So, is my Id not valid or is there something else going on?

Here is my code, starting with the controller.

**SampleDataController.cs**

```
namespace Lothric.UI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SampleDataController : Controller
    {    
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<Car> Cars()
        {
            var data = new List<Car>
            {
                new Car {
                    Id = 1,
                    Make = "Nissan",
                },
                new Car {
                    Id = 2,
                    Make = "Audi"
                }
            };
            return data;
        }

        public class Car
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Make { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**FetchData.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { Key } from 'react';

interface FetchDataExampleState {
    cars: Cars[];
    loading: boolean;
}

export class FetchData extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FetchDataExampleState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { cars: [], loading: true };

        fetch('api/SampleData/Cars')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Cars[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ cars: data, loading: false });
            });
    }

    public render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : FetchData.renderCarsTable(this.state.cars);

        return <div>
            <h1>Cars</h1>
            <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
            { contents }
        </div>;
    }

    private static renderCarsTable(cars: Cars[]) {
        return <ul>
            {cars.map((cars) =>
                <li key={cars.Id}>{cars.Make}</li>
            )}
            </ul>;
    }
}

interface Cars {
    Id: number;
    Make: string;
}
```

I think it may be something simple, but I can't resolve it so need some guidance :) thanks

Comment: is id unique? else i couldn't find any issue.

Comment: Unless there another way to make Id unique, I was under the impression it is.

Comment: This is just a warning so it should render.  What do you get when look at what'S rendered, those the id look unique?

Answer (score 0):

React use [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) method to compare elements and create virtual DOM. If you are using a map (loop) method to create any component then make sure that in the given loop every component has a unique key.

```
private static renderCarsTable(cars: Cars[]) {
    return <ul>
        {carss.map((cars) =>
            <li key={cars.Id}>{cars.Make}</li>
        )}
        </ul>;
}
```

in this case, you have an array of objects of cars that contains Id but you can't make sure that any of 2 items don't have the same ID. In this case, I'll suggest using the index of map function also

```
private static renderCarsTable(cars: Cars[]) {
    return <ul>
        {carss.map((cars, index) =>
            <li key={`${cars.Id}-${index}`}>{cars.Make}</li>
        )}
        </ul>;
}
```

now every element in the map function will have a unique key

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all the responses, everyone.  It seems that it's a simple mistake if you look at the returned raw data from Cars in the console you can see that all the names are lowercase.  So `Id` is `id`, `Make` is `make`.  I changed those items in the interface and then in the render component and it works fine.

```
private static renderCarsTable(cars: Cars[]) {
        return <ul>
            {cars.map((cars) =>
                <li key={cars.id}>{cars.make}</li>
            )}
            </ul>;
    }
}

interface Cars {
    id: number;
    make: string;
}
```

You don't need to change it in the actual Model just in what you are attempting to render.  So, just to reiterate, the render was expecting `id` and `make` but I was defining `Id` and `Make` which doesn't work.